# Inject own implementation of ReactiveMongoApi in Play 2.4.2

Tags: scala, reactivemongo, playframework-2.4, play-reactivemongo

I would like to know if someone can tell me how to inject an own implementation of `ReactiveMongoApi` into one specific controller.

```
class MyController @Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi, val messagesApi: MessagesApi...) extends Controller ...
```

As far as I'm come I don't really get it, how to inject `MyOwnReactiveMongoApi` into `MyController` and only `MyController`. All other controllers should continue to use the default implementation.

I'm currently using:
PlayFramework 2.4.2 and ReactiveMongo 0.11.6.play24

Comment: Don't activate the RM module in the application conf, bind your own API instance from the application loader (or Guice module).

Comment: Thank you, but that's not quite what I'm trying to achieve. This way, I would remove the default implementation and use mine instead. That would lead to the problem, that every controller would use my implementation, but I want to use it only in one (or more) specific controllers.

Comment: Play DI only maintain one binding per type.